# Is it possible to detect Chrome windows that were created from Application Shortcut Tool?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Under `More Tools -> Create application shortcuts...` Chrome offers a tool to create app windows for websites.

Is it possible to detect these windows so that they can be addressed in a Chrome extension?

Comment: Do you have any sample code that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks @Xan. In the meantime we have found a [solution](https://github.com/sindresorhus/merge-windows/commit/bb88ba0af3d1ef5424ec811c376a480472b4a4d7). Is this code piece sufficient for a general answer here?

Comment: Should be, yes. A few words to describe it would help too. Maybe a docs link to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a [solution](https://github.com/sindresorhus/merge-windows/commit/bb88ba0af3d1ef5424ec811c376a480472b4a4d7):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (win) {
-       chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: false}, function (tabs) {
+       chrome.tabs.query({
+           currentWindow: false,
+           windowType: 'normal'
+       }, function (tabs) {
            var tabIds = tabs.map(function (el) {
                return el.id;
            });
```

An action can be limited by choosing `windowType: 'normal'`.

More information: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-WindowType